# How to open programatically Samsung android device contain 'Knox Configure' option programatically in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, samsung-knox

My Xamarin Forms application is released to customers via Samsung Knox settings. My requirement like if any new app version is available and customer still using older version of app, When ever user open the app, programatically need to open 'Knox Configure' settings in android device to update app with latest version. I have googled so much time but not getting any clue. Thanks in advance.

Below is the image which will give idea about which option I am trying to open programatically in Xamarin Forms Application.

[image]